# determine a orthogonal basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ of $\mathbb R^3$, such that $Av_1,Av_2,Av_3$ are pairwise orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Let $A=
 \begin{bmatrix}
1& 0& -4\\
2& 1& 1\\
2& -1& 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

$A^TA=\begin{bmatrix}
9& 0& 0\\
0& 2& 0\\
0& 0& 18
\end{bmatrix}$

I am asked to determine a orthogonal basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ of $\mathbb R^3$, such that $Av_1,Av_2,Av_3$ are pairwise orthogonal.

If we take the columns of $A^TA$ as the basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, they are obviously an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb R^3$  and we can calculate

$A\begin{bmatrix}
9\\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}=$$\begin{bmatrix}
9\\
18 \\
18 
\end{bmatrix}$.

$A\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0 \\
18 
\end{bmatrix}=$$\begin{bmatrix}
-72\\
18 \\
18 
\end{bmatrix}$

$A\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
2 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}=$$\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
2 \\
-2 
\end{bmatrix}$

These vectors are pairwise orthogonal again.

> Could someone explain why this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $Av_1,Av_2,Av_3$ are pairwise orthogonal if

- $v_j^T A^TA v_i=0$

and since $A^TA$ is diagonal the condition is fulfilled since

- $v_j^T A^TA v_i=v_j^T D v_i=d_{ii}v_j^Tv_i=0$

Comment: if $A^TA$ is not diagonal, this does not hold in general?

Comment: @J.D Yes it doesn't work in general.

Comment: but it is always satisfied if the eigenevctors of $A^TA$ are pairwise distinct?

Comment: @J.D in this case it works for any orthogonal basis since $A^TA$ is diagonal since $v_j^T A^TA v_i=v_j^T D v_i=d_{ii}v_j^Tv_i=0$

Comment: @J.D Not necessarly $A^TA$ is always symmetric but in general it is not diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal eigenvectors of $A^TA$ (which is to say that $v^Tw = 0$), then we have
$$
(Av)^T(Aw) = v^T(A^TAw) = \lambda \ v^Tw = \lambda \cdot 0 = 0
$$

Comment: Another perspective comes from considering the singular value decomposition $A = U \Sigma V^T$ of $A$.

Comment: if we consider the SVD, then the entries of $\Sigma$ are the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ and I think they are allways distinct. So we can say this will work always unless we have one or more singular values which are equal to zero? Is this thought correct?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are **not** always distinct.  However, $A^TA$ is always orthogonally diagonalizable by the spectral theorem since it is symmetric

Comment: @J.D I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

The fact that A$^T$A is diagonal shows that A, by definition, is orthogonal. It also means that A$^T$A's columns are multiples of the elementary vectors, and therefore orthogonal. Orthogonality is preserved by orthogonal matrices. That is, if u is orthogonal to v, and A is orthogonal, then Au and Av are orthogonal. So when you take columns from A$^T$A and multiply them by A, you get orthogonal vectors.

Note that because A is orthogonal, when you say

> I am asked to determine a orthogonal basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ of $\mathbb R^3$, such that $Av_1,Av_2,Av_3$ are pairwise orthogonal.

this has a trivial solution: just take the elementary vectors. When you multiply these by A, you get the columns of A, which are orthogonal.

Comment: The usual definition of an orthogonal matrix $A$ is that $A^TA=I$, not simply that this product is diagonal.